# Return a row with the max date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return a row with the max date. Here's my sample table:

```
AAALTLCHANGEREQUESTOR   AAALTLCHANGEVALUE   CREATEDDATETIME
-------------------------------------------------------------------
QPGMR                   13,2020/10/27,0     2020-10-27 11:32:57.000
QPGMR                   EDI                 2020-10-27 11:32:57.000
wethridg                5.10                2021-01-18 14:47:12.000
QPGMR                   3226                2020-10-27 11:32:57.000
```

I need this row returned:

```
wethridg                5.10                2021-01-18 14:47:12.000
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX([AAALTLCHANGEREQUESTOR]) AS 'User',
    MAX([AAALTLCHANGEVALUE]) AS 'Value',
    MAX([CREATEDDATETIME]) AS 'Created Date'
FROM 
    [AX2012_PROD].[dbo].[AAALTLCHANGEREQUESTARCHIVE]
WHERE
    AAAREFNUMVALUE = '17743965'  
    AND AAASENTTOLTL = '1'
```

Here's what it returns:

```
User       Value       Created Date
----------------------------------------------
wethridg    ZRY        2021-01-18 14:47:12.000
```

This is instead returning each max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
select top (1) a.*
from [AX2012_PROD].[dbo].[AAALTLCHANGEREQUESTARCHIVE] a
where a.AAAREFNUMVALUE = '17743965' and a.AAASENTTOLTL = '1'
order by CREATEDDATETIME desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY date descending. FETCH FIRST ROW only.

```
SELECT AAALTLCHANGEREQUESTOR, AAALTLCHANGEVALUE, CREATEDDATETIME
FROM tablename
ORDER BY [CREATEDDATETIME] DESC
OFFSET 0 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```